# What are the scenarios we can use for loop in selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

What is the main use of for loop in Automation testing(Selenium Webdriver?

Comment: Your question is unclear and too broad. A `for` loop is a standard tool in any program.

Answer (score 2):

You would use the `for` loop for iteration over a collection of objects. Number of methods in Selenium return a collection of objects. You would iterate over them with the `for` loop and perform necessary logic within the loop body.

For example `WebDriver` has the following method: `java.util.List<WebElement> findElements(By by)`

You can use the `for` loop to iterate over a `List` of returned WebElements and perform the necessary actions within the loop body.

A small example of `for` loop:

```
// Line below returns a `List` of `WebElements`
List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table/tr"));

// For loop follows
for (int i = 0; i < rows.size(); i++) {
    // Access individual elements this way:
    WebElement currentRow = rows.get(i);
    // Perform an action with currentRow here
}
```

Comment: for example, I want to test the login page of facebook with multiple username and passwords. I am retrieving data from an excel sheet. Then using for loop how I can write the script.

Comment: @sai that is the absolutely wrong question to ask. It is like stating "i have a hammer - now what do I do with it". You should not start with the "tool", start with what you are trying to do. Are you trying to iterate over something, use a `for` loop. And **please** read a **basic java tutorial** if you do not know what a `for` loop is.

Comment: I know for loop is using to iterate over something but in selenium, I struck in one scenario that is in excel sheet I have 5 usernames in one column and 5 passwords in one column. I have to pass those in one login page using for loop.                                                                                                      
 username                 password
ravi@gmail.com         hfuehfue
kiran@gmail.com         efnen
ramesh@gmail.com efefefefef

Comment: @sai, you are asking a new question. My recommendation is to put a few lines of code together and post a new question for this. Also, make sure that what you are doing is legal.

Comment: @sai What you just asked is `data-driven` testing and you don't need to use `for` loop to perform this kind of tests. There are several testing frameworks like `JUnit` or TestNG` for Java to run test scenarios based on excel (or any other file) through `DataProvider`. The DataProvider run test after test with a different set of data. For example the 1st row of data = 1st test, 2nd row of data = 2nd test.
Also, in order to get the answer to your question you should limit your question to a specific problem. We are here to help but not to do all your job for you. We are here to guide.